# Construct parsing for unaligned int field?

Tags: python, construct

I am using this nice little package "[construct](http://construct.wikispaces.com/)" for binary data parsing. However, I ran into a case where the format is defined as:

```
31     24 23              0
+-------------------------+
| status |  an int number |
+-------------------------+
```

Basically, the higher 8 bits are used for status, and 3 bytes left for integer: an int type with higher bits masked off. I am a bit lost on what is the proper way of defining the format:

- The brute force way is to define it as `ULInt32` and do bit masking myself
- Is there anyway I can use BitStruct to save the trouble?

**Edit**

Assuming Little Endian and based on jterrace's example and swapped=True suggestion, I think this is what will work in my case:

```
sample = "\xff\x01\x01\x01"
c = BitStruct("foo", BitField("i", 24, swapped=True), BitField("status", 8))
c.parse(sample)
Container({'i': 66047, 'status': 1})
```

Thanks

Oliver

Comment: What is wrong with using integer operations for a format defined on low-level integers? `val >> 24` and `val & 0xfff` are pretty well readable.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I'm guessing it's not that simple. This might be inside of a struct or an array, and he's already using construct to parse out those datastructures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be easy if construct contained Int24 types, but it doesn't. Instead, you can specify the bit lengths yourself like this:

```
>>> from construct import BitStruct, BitField
>>> sample = "\xff\x01\x01\x01"
>>> c = BitStruct("foo", BitField("status", 8), BitField("i", 24))
>>> c.parse(sample)
Container({'status': 255, 'i': 65793})
```

Note: The value `\x01\x01\x01` is `65536 + 256 + 1 = 65793`

Comment: I think I am confused somewhere on the bit order: when you write "\xff\x01\x01\x01", is \xff the high byte? [24-32)? For some reason, I always thought this should be 24-bit, 8-bit in that order. However, since both answers defined that way ... I am thinking I got it backward, can you clarify? thanks

Comment: @Oliver it depends whether it's big-endian or little-endian. What format is your data in? Can you give an example of one of your byte strings?

Comment: I know I am using little endian for sure, but I don't have a specific byte string as example. I did a few test, \xff seems belong to bit 0-7.

Comment: @Oliver Just switch the positions in BitStruct if necessary, and you might need to pass ``swapped=True`` to ``BitField`` constructor to reverse the endianness.

Answer (score 0):

```
BitStruct("foo",
          BitField("status", 8),
          BitField("number", 24))
```

Comment: Should the order be reversed so that BitField(24) comes first? thanks

Comment: As discussed with jterrace, this assumes high-endiannes. Just reversing the order of the fields won't help you, because the 24bit field would still have reversed values.

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes swapped=True should reverse it though

Comment: Yup, I was just commenting on field order :)